How to search elasticsearch using spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch?
I want to use the following elastic search query in Java to search through all my documents in my index.
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "my search input"
    }
  }
}

When I use CURL it works fine and i get results back, but when i try to use this query in Java, it complains and gives me the following exception:
co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.ElasticsearchException: [es/search] failed: [parsing_exception] unknown query [query]

This is what my code looks like in Java:
    @GetMapping("/search")
    public void searchResume(@RequestParam(name = "search") String query) {
        Query q = new StringQuery("""
                {
                  "query": {
                    "query_string": {
                      "query": "my search input"
                    }
                  }
                }
                """);
        System.out.println(operations.search(q, Resume.class));
    }

Does someone know why it works using CURL but does not work when using Java and spring-data-elasticsearch?
I tried googling a lot and even asked chatgpt for help but I can't seem to find out why it doesn't work. Thank you in advance.

I'm pretty sure the StringQuery object is already adding the {"query":...} wrapper when converted internally to the final http request. I think the fix is to simply omit the "query" so that your final string is:
{
     "query_string": {"query": "my search input"}
}


Thank you so much that fixed the issue!
